# Sphinx sql_attr_bigint on a 32-bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, sphinx, 32-bit

I am running sphinx on a 32 bit machine and want to get the sql_attr_bigint to work.

1. Can this be done?
2. Should it work by default?
3. Do I have to re-compile and make any changes at compile time?
4. What effect will it have on performance?

My table id fits in 32-bits. I just need this with one attribute and it must be 64 bits.

Could the problem be in PHP?

Comment: the problem was in PHP. When I assigned the value from the result array to a variable PHP messed up the value. Sphinx is working fine with bigints on a 32-bit comp

Comment: You should add that as an 'answer' to the question. And the mark it as 'accepted'. That means it can show as a a solved question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in PHP. When I assigned the value from the result array to a variable PHP messed up the value. Sphinx is working fine with bigints on a 32-bit comp.

This can still work on PHP as sphinx returns attribute values as strings in the results array ( regardless of how they were stored in the index). So I can just use the string value in the PHP code.